# Loud sound and crystal clock,how big problem it is?

Tags: crystal, sound, vibration

I want to use piezo crystal clock in place where loud sounds exist,I worry that it might decrease the performance of the clock,create spurious tones for example.

The db level at the clock will be around 100 db,or 2 pascal pressure.Clock will be typical small clock,it will not have two or three layers of metal around it like some of the big expensive oven clocks.

I think damage is unlikely becose manufacturers often test the clocks for g-force and there is no way sound of that amplitude is going to shake them beyond those specifications,but some kind if clock signal degradation seems quite possible.

The question is,is sound at those not too high levels ( 100db ) problem? Does it create some degree of clock signal degradation for your typical small piezo clock? Do you have any experience,or did you ever heard or read about sound affecting piezo crystal oscillators? Is this common problem or are crystal clock relatively immune to interference from sound?

Comment: Go look for a high g crystal. There are several that can handle many thousands of g.

Comment: Also make sure your board won't flex too much and crack MLCCs..

Comment: Sound is not a problem at that level. However, if it is being mechanically coupled into the crystal as vibration then it might well be. In other words, if it is strapped to the case of a noisy motor it is going to fare worse than just sitting close to it in air

Comment: Do not consider g without t and m, and that converts to velocity and momentum which converts to fragility boundary curve and damaged xtal or electrode stress and frequency drift.  It depends on the spectral amplitude, trust me, isolate it. Test it. but first spec drift.

Comment: What is "t and m"?